# How to separate GraphQL queries from string in URQL?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, urql

I am developing a GraphQL testing tool. Let's say I have an input field where users can write down the query and click on the run button to run the query.

```
query Message {
  messages {
    user
    content
  }
}


subscription RealtimeMessage {
  messages{
    content
    user
  }
}

mutation SendMessage {
  postMessage(user: "User ID", content: "Hi")
}
```

If there are multiple queries, I would like to show the user a dropdown to select the one to run. In the above example, we have 3 queries. If the user runs the query I would like to show a dropdown where the user will see 3 names `Message`, `RealtimeMessage`, `SendMessage`. And whichever user select I would like to pass that specific query to run.

I am using `urql` for GraphQL in my Vue project.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component that uses `useQuery` reactively based on a query that you pass in as a prop.  Something like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { useQuery } from '@urql/vue';
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';
  import { PropType } from 'vue';

  const props = defineProps({
    query: { type: Object as PropType<DocumentNode>, required: true },
  });

  // result will be reactive
  const result = useQuery({
    query: props.query,    
  });
</script>
```

You have to pass in a DocumentNode as the query parameter - something like

```
gql`
query Message {
  messages {
    user
    content
  }
}`
```

See https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/vue/#run-a-first-query for more details on the reactive useQuery()